# How to write the results of Azure ML web service to the azure sql database (The output of Azure ML web service is in Json structure)

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-scheduler, azure-machine-learning-service

The results can be written to SQL Azure using the writer module in the experiment but after publishing the web service the output comes in the Json Structure and it doesn't go to the writer module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set output port and use Batch execution service - details are provided here - [Publish web service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-publish-a-machine-learning-web-service/) and [consume web service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-consume-web-services/)

Comment: so do i need to edit the sample C# code given in batch execution file?

Comment: response request or Batch execution - which one is suitable for scheduling job in Azure Schedular

Comment: Batch execution is suitable for scheduler

Comment: So i have removed the web service output but the no of rows getting appended is different when i test the web service and when i call from external c# code.. can you please help

Comment: Can you please attach your graph and provide a URL for your experiment?